# Reproduzir uma série de audios no android

Tags: java, android, áudio

Boa noite, alguém já fez ou sabe como reproduzir uma série de áudios ?
Eu estou tentando fazer um app parecido com aquele jogo Genius. E gostaria de poder reproduzir uma sequência de áudios que eu vou pré determinar. Queria poder fazer isso dentro de um loop, só que ele só executa o ultimo áudio.
Alguém tem alguma dica ou pode me informar como fazer isso ?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você deve colocar seus arquivos de áudio na pasta `raw` do seu projeto, feito isso utilizando o objeto `MediaPlayer` basta inicializar o objeto para poder utilizalo. Exemplo:

Criação

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
```

Utilizando

```
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.pause();
```

[Mais opções](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm)

Comment: Cara, isso não funciona. Estava fazendo assim. Por exemplo se faço um for ele só reproduz o último arquivo.

Comment: Poste seu código aqui, ai fica mais facil!